# jquery array push using map

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
function tracks(id) {

    $.get("https://api.spotify.com/v1/albums/" + id + "/tracks", function(data, status) {
        data.items.map(function(item) {
            console.log(item.name)
        });
    });
}

}

var json = [{
    track: [tracks('5KM8hybz2fW6ThBDWETbX1')]
}]
```

I'm getting my value in the console.log, but I'm not able to push it to object; I tried return `item.name` it's `null`.

Comment: where are  you trying to push the `item.name` to an array?

Comment: @nnunes10 what should I do then?

Comment: If the JSON in your question is what's being returned, there are no objects in the array with `name` properties...

Comment: var array = new Array(); array.push(item.name);

Comment: @nnunes10 can you modify from here? https://jsfiddle.net/x9ao9hqd/

I tried that it doesn't work.

Comment: Your question/example codes are different. Are you trying to get one particular track from a list of tracks?

Comment: @Quentin, this isn't a duplicate.

Comment: @Andy — Yes, it is. It is making an asynchronous request using jQuery's `get` and then trying to return the value from that to the point where `tracks` was called.

Comment: @Quentin 2 ajax is calling different endpoint, i need the album id to use another endpoint to call for the tracks.

Comment: @Jennifer — Which brings us right back to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/

Comment: @Quentin why do I need that? I can get the tracks.. I think you missed understood my question.

Comment: @Jennifer — Are you really saying that `track: [tracks('5KM8hybz2fW6ThBDWETbX1')]` puts a useful value in that array? Since, given your code, it should put `undefined` there.

Comment: @Quentin look at my example here http://jsfiddle.net/x9ao9hqd/, I'm stuck appending my array to objects.

Comment: @Quentin sorry I thought above code is similar to my actual problem.

Comment: @Quentin, yeah, my mistake. Voting to close because the question is still very unclear.